# Cygwin bash.exe cannot run make, works in cmd.exe

Tags: c, bash, cmd, makefile, cygwin

I am having issues running any make command in a Cygwin bash terminal. The following is the error that is returned.

"'ygdrive' is not reconized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

However I am able to properly run the make file using cmd.exe, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Eric E

Comment: which make.exe are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are referencing a path in some recipe with `\cygdrive\<letter>\...`. `bash` interprets a single backslash as an escape character and therefore ignores the `c` directly following it.

Solutions:

1. If you want the `Makefile` to be portable to Unix systems, just write forward slashes in paths like this `/cygdrive/<letter>/...`.
2. If you instead want the `Makefile` to be compatible with `cmd`, too, use double backslashes like `\\cygdrive\\<letter\\...` -- both `bash` and `cmd` will understand this.

In any case, such a path should be in a `make` variable because it is probably completely different on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution by Felix might be the answer for others, however the solution for my problem was removing "SHELL=C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe" from the top of my Makefile..